# My insertion python sort is always placing the second number at the beginning

Tags: python, list, sorting, iteration, insertion-sort

my code is working mostly fine except for a small bug where it is placing the second element at the beginning no matter the value e.g. 1,6,2,9,3,8,4,7,5,0 would become 6,0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9

I've tried altering the numbers in the FOR loop a bit but other than that genuinely cannot see what's wrong

```
def InsertionSort(array):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        for j in range(len(array)):
            if array[i] <= array[j+1]:
                new = array.pop(i)
                array.insert(j+1,new)
                break
            elif array[i] > array[j+1]:
                continue
        print (array)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem there is, that you switch the position of the second element with the first, but later on not compare it anymore.

Here an implementation which is close to yours, with slight changes to take care of all the entries

```
ar =[1,6,2,9,3,8,4,7,5,0]
def InsertionSort(array):
    for i in range(len(array)):
            val = array[i]
            while( i > 0 and array[i-1] > val):
                array[i] = array[i-1]
                i = i - 1
            array[i] = val
    print (array)

InsertionSort(ar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time you modify the collection you are looping over, you can get different behavior than what you expect. This is especially true when you are removing items from the collection since it messes with the current index.

Here is an example that simply swaps the orders of elements (and also prints debug information along the way so you can see exactly what is happening):

```
def insertionSort(my_list):
    # for every element in our array
    for index in range(1, len(my_list)):
        current = my_list[index]
        position = index

        while position > 0 and my_list[position-1] > current:
            print("Swapped {} for {}".format(my_list[position], my_list[position-1]))
            my_list[position] = my_list[position-1]
            print(my_list)
            position -= 1

        my_list[position] = current

    return my_list

my_list = [8,2,1,3,5,4]

print(insertionSort(my_list))
```